# Пользовательский класс String уточняющие вопросы

Tags: c++, ссылки, конструктор

В образовательных целях изучаю код пользовательского класса String [c данного ресурса](http://cppstudio.com/post/6110/)

Приведу сам код с примера чтобы было проще:

```
#ifndef STRING_H
#define STRING_H

#include <iostream>

namespace STD
{

int StrLen(char*);
void StrCpy(char*, char*);
bool StrCmp(char*, char*);

class String
{
public:
    String(char* _str = "");
    String(const String&);
    ~String();

    String& operator=(const String&);
    friend String operator+(const String&, const String&);
    String& operator+=(const String&);

    friend bool operator==(const String&, const String&);
    friend bool operator!=(const String&, const String&);
    friend bool operator>(const String&, const String&);
    friend bool operator>=(const String&, const String&);
    friend bool operator<(const String&, const String&);
    friend bool operator<=(const String&, const String&);

    const char& operator[](int) const;
    char& operator[](int);

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const String&);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, String&);

private:
    char* str;
};

String::String(char* _str)
{
    str = new char[StrLen(_str)+1];
    StrCpy(str, _str);
}

String::String(const String& rhs)
{
    str = new char[StrLen(rhs.str)+1];
    StrCpy(str, rhs.str);
}

String::~String()
{
    delete str;
}

// ---

String& String::operator=(const String& rhs)
{
    if (this != &rhs)
    {
        delete[] this->str;
        this->str = new char[StrLen(rhs.str)+1];
        StrCpy(this->str, rhs.str);
    }
    return *this;
}

String& String::operator+=(const String& rhs)
{
    int sz = StrLen(this->str) + StrLen(rhs.str);
    char* ts = new char[sz+1];

    for (int i = 0; i < StrLen(this->str); i++)
        ts[i] = this->str[i];
    for (int ii = StrLen(this->str), j = 0; ii <= sz; ii++, j++)
        ts[ii] = rhs.str[j];

    delete this->str;
    this->str = ts;

    return *this;
}

String operator+(const String& lhs, const String& rhs)
{
    String ts = lhs;
    return ts += rhs;
}

// --

bool operator==(const String& lhs, const String& rhs)
{
    return StrCmp(lhs.str, rhs.str);
}

bool operator!=(const String& lhs, const String& rhs)
{
    return !(StrCmp(lhs.str, rhs.str));
}

bool operator>(const String& lhs, const String& rhs)
{
    return (StrLen(lhs.str) > StrLen(rhs.str)) ? true : false;
}

bool operator>=(const String& lhs, const String& rhs)
{
    return (StrLen(lhs.str) >= StrLen(rhs.str)) ? true : false;
}

bool operator<(const String& lhs, const String& rhs)
{
    return (StrLen(lhs.str) < StrLen(rhs.str)) ? true : false;
}

bool operator<=(const String& lhs, const String& rhs)
{
    return (StrLen(lhs.str) <= StrLen(rhs.str)) ? true : false;
}

// ---

const char& String::operator[](int i) const
{
    //std::cerr << "Index out of range. \n";
    return (i >= 0 && i < StrLen(this->str)) ? this->str[i] : 0;
}

char& String::operator[](int i)
{
    static char DUMMY; DUMMY = '';
    //std::cerr << "Index out of range. \n";
    return (i >= 0 && i < StrLen(this->str)) ? this->str[i] : DUMMY;
}

// ---

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const String& obj)
{
    return os << obj.str;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, String& obj)
{
    char BUFF[2048];
    is.getline(BUFF, sizeof BUFF);
    obj = BUFF;

    return is;
}

// ---

int StrLen(char* _str)
{
    int size = 0;

    for (; _str[size] != 0; size++);
    return size;
}

void StrCpy(char* in_str, char* src_str)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < StrLen(in_str); i++)
        in_str[i] = src_str[i];
}

bool StrCmp(char* str_f, char* str_s)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (; str_f[i] == str_s[i] && i < StrLen(str_f); i++);

    return (i == StrLen(str_f)) ? true : false;
}

}

#endif
```

У меня несколько уточняющих вопросов:

1. Я попробовал воспользоваться данным классом и создать экземпляр с помощью выражения:

   ```
   String instance
   ```

   Но компилятор заругался на отсутствие дефолтного конструктора. Каким должен быть дефолтный конструктор чтобы это выражение создавало новые экземпляры без ошибок?
2. Я не совсем понимаю какую форму создания экземпляров обслуживает второй конструктор:

   ```
   String::String(const String& rhs)
   {                                 
       str = new char[StrLen(rhs.str)+1];
       StrCpy(str, rhs.str);
   }
   ```

Насколько я понимаю первый вариант контструктора позволяет создавать строки с текстовыми литералами:

```
String* string1 = new String("some string")
```

Я пробовал передавать в качестве аргумента ссылки на первый экземпляр, но видимо делаю это неточно. Подскажите каким образом я должен создавать экземпляры используя второй конструктор.

Comment: 2 - это конструктор копии

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста как передать копию в виде аргумента.

Comment: `String string1("some string"); String string2(string1);` Вдобавок, конструктор копии будет вызываться при передаче в функцию параметра типа String по-значению

Comment: Я так пробовал и в этом варианте и с оператором new: String string2 = new String(string1) В обоих случаях у меня ошибка на этапе компиляции: cannot convert argument 1 from 'String *' to 'char*' очевидно он пытается создать экземпляр только по первому конструктору.

Comment: Потому что он находит оператор приведения к char

Comment: Сработал такой вариант: String* string2(string1);

Comment: Откуда такая эклектическая мешанина из `delete` и `delete []`? Здесь применимо только `delete []`. Причем аффтар периодически об этом вспоминает. Но потом снова забывает. А потмо снова вспоминает....

Comment: @Harry, что-то ты странно исправил)

Comment: @Qwertiy Оставил тебе :)

Comment: У вас **очень** странно определено сравнение. Например, для строк `a = "a"` и `b = "b"` у вас не выполняется ни `a == b`, ни `a > b`, ни `a < b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Если ваш компилятор разрешает вам приводить строковые литералы к типу `char *`, то у вашего класса *есть* дефолтный конструктор. Никакой ошибки отсутствия дефолтного конструктора в таком случае быть не может. Вы что-то выдумываете.
2. Это конструктор копирования, который будет вызываться в массе разных ситуаций. В частности

   ```
   String a;
   String b = a; // <- конструктор копирования
   ```

---

Однако:

1. `String(char* _str = "")` - ошибка, код некомпилируем. Язык С++ уже давно запретил приводить строковые литералы к типу `char *`
2. Деструктор

   ```
   String::~String()
   {
       delete str;
   }
   ```

   Память, выделенная `new []` освобождается только `delete []`. Не `free`, не `delete`, не `vasya_pupkin_dealloc`, а именно и только `delete []`. (Можно `vasya_pupkin_dealloc`, но только если там внутри `delete []`.)
3. Оператор `[]`

   ```
   const char& String::operator[](int i) const
   {
       //std::cerr << "Index out of range. \n";
       return (i >= 0 && i < StrLen(this->str)) ? this->str[i] : 0;
   }
   ```

   В случае выхода за пределы массива возвращается ссылка на временный объект `(const char) 0`. Временный объект будут сразу уничтожен - возвращенная ссылка "повиснет", поведение не определено.

   Да и вообще идея возвращения ссылки на "что-то" в случае выхода за пределы массива - порочна чуть менее, чем полностью.
4. Функция `StrCpy`

   ```
   void StrCpy(char* in_str, char* src_str)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < StrLen(in_str); i++)
           in_str[i] = src_str[i];
   }
   ```

   Если мы копируем `src_str` в `in_str`, то в условии продолжения цикла должна фигурировать `StrLen(src_str)`, а не `StrLen(in_str)`. И при строгом неравенстве функция "забудет" скопировать нулевой терминатор.
5. `StrCmp` сравнивает символы до длины первой строки, совершенно не беспокоясь о длине второй. Т.е. `StrCmp("abc", "a")` спокойно вылетает за пределы второй строки, а `StrCmp("abc", "abcd")` считает строки равными.

   Это поведение передается операторам `==` и `!=`.
6. В функциях `StrLen`, `StrCpy` и `StrCmp` вдруг куда-то пропадает забота о константной корректности. Это при том, что в классе такая забота видна явно.

   Так как исправлять ошибку с `char *` в конструкторе придется, вам понадобятся и эти функции с грамотно оформленной константной корректностью.
7. Код изобилует повторными вызовами `StrLen`... Я понял - автор не хочет хранить длину строки. Но может быть все таки хотя бы внутри методов можно было вызывать `StrLen` один раз и сохранять результат в локальной переменной, а не вызвать `StrLen` снова и снова для одних и тех же данных?

   Уж в `StrCpy` и `StrCmp` можно, наверное, было обойтись без вызовов `StrLen`?
8. Оператор чтения из потока

   ```
   std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, String& obj)
   {
       char BUFF[2048];
       is.getline(BUFF, sizeof BUFF);
       obj = BUFF;

       return is;
   }
   ```

   Писали мы, значит, писали поддержку строки произвольной длины, а затем решили, что `2048` должно хватить всем...
9. Операторы `==` сравнивают (пытаются сравнивать) содержимое строк, а операторы `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=` - сравнивают только длины строк?
10. Названия низкоуровневых функций работы со строками - очевидная калька с названий стандартных функций из библиотеки языка С. Однако булевская семантика функции `StrCmp` *противоположна* булевской семантике стандартной функции. Это для проверки на бдительность читателя кода?

    (Использование стандартной `strcmp` в булевской семантике, типа `!strcmp(a, b)` - практика, конечно, дикая и те, кто к этому привык, сами виноваты. Но тем не менее...)
11. Выражения вида

    ```
    return (i == StrLen(str_f)) ? true : false;
    ```

    Дело вкуса, конечно, но вообще-то можно написать по человечески

    ```
    return i == StrLen(str_f);
    ```

Comment: 10 - в чём дикость? простой вариант вернуть три состояния же.

Comment: 8 – а что ж вы хотели, это единственная нетривиальная функция во всём классе :-P

Answer (score 2):

Не понимаю, с чего ваш компилятор заругался - ведь ваш

```
String(char* _str = "");
```

и есть дефолтный конструктор - со значением `""`. Вы точно все написали, как есть? по крайней мере у меня компилятор на отсутствие дефолтного конструктора не ругался.

Второй конструктор - копирующий. Он будет использован, например, в случае

```
String s("Hello");
String q(s);
```

или

```
void f(String s) { ... };

String s("Hello");
f(s);
```

Еще - вот тут `DUMMY = '';` явно пробел нужен. Только мне не нравится сама идея возврата чего-то при выходе за пределы массива. Я бы лучше исключение генерировал...

Comment: В моем случае ругался на дефолтный конструктор когда я создавал экземпляр без фигурных скобок: String s. С фигурными скобками экземпляр создавался String s(), но после этого он отказывался работать с оператором new : expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Comment: `String(char* _str = "");` нормальный компилятор пошлет погулять с таким кодом. И он будет абсолютно прав. Студийный компилятор до 2013 включительно часто закрывал глаза на подобное. Но 2015 уже такое не позволяет, если явно не попросить.

Comment: Я пользуюсь Visual Studio 2015, компилятор не заругался на такой код. Поясните пожалуйста что с ним не так, то что _str записал в виде литерала а не массива?

Comment: строка в кавычках - это константа. И присвоить константную строку неконстантому указателю - можно, но будет печаль (при попытке модифицировать). Что бы успокоить компилятор, нужно `-Zc:strictStrings`. (если ещё не понятно - это присваивание - это просто присваивание указателя. А "" может указывать на константую память. В любом случае, если вызвать delete  для такого - будет падение)

Comment: Нет нельзя. Строковый литерал уже давно не приводим к типу `char *`. Только `const char *`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

```
char npos = '\0';

  String::String()
         :str(&npos)  //char*
         ,len(0)      //size_t размер строки
         ,memory(0){}  //size_t размер используемой памяти
```

Comment: а когда деструктор прибежит? похоже будет весело.

Comment: ну так ~string(){ if(str != &npos){ delete[]str} }

Comment: только это в нескольких местах нужно будет писать.